# Minecraft Forge Setup JAVA_HOME Variable - Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, minecraft-forge

As the title suggested, I have Ubuntu, and I was trying to tun the command ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace in the Minecraft Forge folder, but I got the following error at about 70%

```
Execution failed for task ':recompileMc'.
```

> Unable to find a javac compiler;
>     com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>     Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>     It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

While I have the JAVA_HOME variable set to the JDK and not the JRE, I confirmed it by running export in terminal, and the following was stated

```
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

Please help me with this problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

JRE stands for Java Runtime Enviroment. usually the one without the compiler.

it should be jdk, not jre

Also, I suggest installing jdk 8 if you are planning on making mods for 1.8+

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html